# Kinematics and Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, collision

If a body loses half of its velocity on penetrating 3cm in a wooden block, then how much will it penetrate more before coming to rest? How does answer come out to be 1cm?

Comment: You seem to be new here. There is a very strict [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange/715#715) about _beginner_ and [_homework_](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) questions. your question's level of difficulty is only 1% of IIT-JEE level. If you really want an answer then you will have to show whatever you have tried. You will also have to format your question up to the mark with proper grammar. Last but not the least remember pronouns are always capitalized("I" in your comments).

Comment: This is the culture of this website my friend.

Comment: @user45332, I have answered your question below.  It will travel 1 cm more.

Comment: @user45332: your question was answered, in some detail, in the question [Number of planks required to stop the bullet](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110401/number-of-planks-required-to-stop-the-bullet)